# Capture successful prestashop order in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, prestashop-1.6, google-analytics-firebase, payu

I use Prestashop V1.6.1.11, and PayU payment module. I have configured the Google Analytics module.
Currently the successful order is not captured in analytics.
I think this is because the payment module, on successful payment is redirecting to `order-detail` page when logged in or `guest-tracking` page for guest users instead of `order-confirmation` page. 
In the goal url's of Google Analytics I have added `/order-detail` and `/guest-tracking` as goals but it doesn't help.
Is there a way to capture order confirmation in this case?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the code manually to send an event to Google Analytics on your `/order-detail`, `/order-detail` and `/guest-tracking` pages and then use that event to trigger your successful order goal.

For example:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Order', 'Successful');
```